# Matplotlib data plot contains too many labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I tried to visualize csv data with a 3D graph.

My code is included below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d


MY_FILE = 'total_watt.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(MY_FILE, parse_dates=[0], header=None, names=['datetime', 'consumption'])

df['date'] = [x.date() for x in df['datetime']]
df['time'] = [x.time() for x in df['datetime']]

pv = df.pivot(index='time', columns='date', values='consumption')

# to avoid holes in the surface
pv = pv.fillna(0.0)

xx, yy = np.mgrid[0:len(pv),0:len(pv.columns)]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

surf=ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, pv.values, cmap='jet', cstride=1, rstride=1)

fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=10)

dates = [x.strftime('%m-%d') for x in pv.columns]
times = [x.strftime('%H:%M') for x in pv.index]
consumptions = [x for x in pv.values]

ax.set_title('Energy consumptions Clusters')
ax.set_xlabel('time', color='lightseagreen')
ax.set_ylabel('date(year 2011)', color='lightseagreen')
ax.set_zlabel('energy consumption', color='lightseagreen')
ax.set_xticks(xx[::10,0])
ax.set_xticklabels(times[::10], color='lightseagreen')
ax.set_yticks(yy[0,::10])
ax.set_yticklabels(dates[::10], color='lightseagreen')
ax.set_zticklabels(consumptions[::100000], color='lightseagreen')

ax.set_axis_bgcolor('black')



plt.show()
```

Although I successfully colored;

x-axis  `ax.set_xlabel('time', color='lightseagreen')`

y-axis  `ax.set_ylabel('date(year 2011)', color='lightseagreen')`

z-axis  `ax.set_zlabel('energy consumption', color='lightseagreen')`

ticks in `x-axis ax.set_xticklabels(times[::10], color='lightseagreen')`

ticks in `y-axis  ax.set_yticklabels(dates[::10], color='lightseagreen')`

I cannot color ticks in z-axis properly, because x-axis plot 'time' and y-axis plot date, which are defined properly. I think the way I defined consumptions (`consumptions = [x for x in pv.values]`) is incorrect and it causes this error..

The 3d graph, I got from this code is

[image]

What my cause my issue and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to get the purpose of your question and wasn't able to test it but I think you should change the length of the zticks list:

```
# resizing the yticks list and changing the values
ax.set_yticks(yy[0,::10])
# changing the yticks labels
ax.set_yticklabels(dates[::10], color='lightseagreen')
# changing the zticks labels whereas zticks is not resized
# try adding
ax.set_zticks(consumptions[::100000])
# before changing the labels
ax.set_zticklabels(consumptions[::100000], color='lightseagreen')
```

Sorry I couldn't check if it works